# Should I do `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` before `throw new InterruptedIOException()`?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I implement `MyInputStream.read()` and notice that an `InterruptedException` may happen within this function. After some searching I have found that it is common to catch the `InterruptedException` and re-throw an `InterruptedIOException`, something like:

```
    try {
        ...
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // <=== ???
        throw new InterruptedIOException();
    }
```

but only about 50% of code samples do `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.
Well, it is agreed that [the worst thing you can do with `InterruptedException` is swallow it](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html), but ***should I reinterrupt the current thread before throwing a different exception?***

PRO: a single interruption request may have multiple "recipients."

CONTRA: some functionality [like logging](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4329256) may be not working before the interrupt status is cleared, which may cause subtle bugs.

CONTRA: we get two notifications about the interrupt request: the thread's interrupted status and the exception. Initially, there is only one notification: either the thread's interrupted status is true or an `InterruptedException` is thrown, but not both.

PRO: nobody really tests the code against i/o exceptions that may be thrown, and the `InterruptedIOException` is different from other i/o exceptions; a `catch(IOException)` clause may swallow the interrupted status.

PS It looks like whatever I do, the problem that `InterruptedIOException` is a very special kind of `IOException` requiring a special handler will not be solved.

PPS (EDIT)
I cannot let the original `InterruptedException` propagate because `InputStream.read()` cannot throw `InterruptedException` (it `throws IOException` and does not throw anything else).
And I cannot predict the context in which `MyInputStream.read()` will be called: an instance of `MyInputStream` may be passed to any Java or 3rd-party library function that takes an `InputStream` argument.

As to [the old bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4329256), it looks like it was just closed, not fixed; and the very idea of the interrupted status is that the code would behave differently.

Comment: What I don't like from `InterruptedIOException` is that it does not facilitate embedding other exception as the cause. Depending on the context, I would just `throw new IOException(e)` so that I can still get the underlying cause when I caught the exception on the upper layer.

Comment: @IbrahimArief  Use `initCause(...)`.  Three lines but it gets the job done: `InterruptedIOException ioExc = new InterruptedIOException(); ioExc.initCause(e); throw ioExc;`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest throwing a **[ClosedByInterruptException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html)**. Although it belongs to the NIO library, it has a better defined API than the old [InterruptedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html), making it easier to handle. For example:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    close(); // obeying API of ClosedByInterruptException
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // again, obeying API
    throw new ClosedByInterruptException();
}
```

See also [Thread#interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29). If instead you want to re-throw the original exception, you can use:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

So you keep the stack trace. The interrupt status is left clear in this case, as the API for [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) suggests.

Comment: This answer seems best. As [Stephen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33757384/2402790) says, the poster's contra about interrupt status and logging can safely be discounted. And the contra about two notifications is addressed here by the clear and precise meaning of the ClosedByInterruptException.

Answer (score 1):

> ... should I reinterrupt the current thread before throwing a different exception?

If something upstack is going to examine the interrupt flag, then yes.  Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

> CONTRA: some functionality like logging may be not working before the interrupt status is cleared, which may cause subtle bugs.

By my reading of the analysis, the bug you linked to only applies to Java 6 and earlier, and only for the Solaris platform.  You can probably discount it now.  (Unless you have a customer with deeeep pockets, you should not be doing significant application for Java 6 or earlier.)

> CONTRA: we get two notifications about the interrupt request: the thread's interrupted status and the exception.

They are qualitatively different kinds of notification ...

> PS It looks like whatever I do, the problem that InterruptedIOException is a very special kind of IOException requiring a special handler will not be solved.

In fact, a better strategy might be to set the interrupted flag in the catch for the `InterruptedIOException` ... or simply allow the original `Interrupted` exception to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the following reasoning:

1. `InterruptedException` MUST NOT be swallowed,
2. any `IOException` (and, in particular, `InterruptedIOException`) MAY
   be swallowed, that is, consumed by 3rd party code
3. `IOException` is intended to inform about events that happen with i/o, not about changes in the thread status
4. Some code that we cannot control may either set or clear the thread interrupted status before throwing or re-throwing `InterruptedIOException`

I decided that:

1. ***the current thread MUST be reinterrupted before throwing an `InterruptedIOException`.***
2. the code handling `InterruptedIOException` SHOULD NOT assume any particular state of the thread interrupted status
3. this behavior MUST be documented:

   ```
   @throws InterruptedIOException if the current thread is interrupted (the thread
           interrupted status is true when InterruptedIOException is thrown)
   @throws IOException if this stream is closed or another IOException occurs.

   Note that due to possible interference from 3rd-party code, handlers 
   of InterruptedIOException should not assume any particular state
   of the thread interrupted status when they are invoked.
   ```